# LottieDrawable is not playing the animation in GraphicOverlay.Graphic

Tags: java, android, graphics, lottie

I am trying to use `LottieDrawable` to draw a simple animation. But the animation is not played.

I saw in old issues that you need to call `mLottieDrawable.setCallBack(this)`
but since I am extending `GraphicOverlay.Graphic`, I don't know what should I use inside `setcallBack()`

Below is the code I have used ->

```
public class PoseGraphic extends GraphicOverlay.Graphic {
    LottieDrawable mLottieDrawable;

    public PoseGraphic() {
        mLottieDrawable = new LottieDrawable();
        mLottieDrawable.enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove(true);
        LottieResult<LottieComposition> result = LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(context, R.raw.heart);
        mLottieDrawable.setComposition(result.getValue());
        mLottieDrawable.setRepeatCount(LottieDrawable.INFINITE);
        mLottieDrawable.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        mLottieDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
```

Version of Lottie -
5.2.0

Version of Android -
Android 12

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

set bounds:

```
mLottieDrawable.setBounds(
                    leftBound,
                    topBound,
                    rightBound,
                    bottomBound)
```